# Node.js (with express & bodyParser): unable to obtain form-data from post request

Tags: node.js, express, post, multipartform-data, body-parser

I can't seem to recover the form-data of a post request sent to my Node.js server. I've put below the server code and the post request (sent using postman in chrome):

**Post request**

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"

jem
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

**NodeJS server code**

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,accept,access_token,X-Requested-With');
    next();
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.json({ message: 'I am groot!' });   
});

// Login
router.route('/login')

    .post(function(req, res){

        console.log('Auth request recieved');

        // Get the user name
        var user = req.body.userName;

        var aToken = getToken(user);

        res.json({

            'token':'a_token'
        });
    });

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
```

The login method tries to obtain the `req.body.userName`, however, `req.body` is always empty.
I've seen other cases on SO describing such behavior but none of the related answers did apply here.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: The issue is that the request's body is [a `multipart` message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) and the `body-parser` module does not support parsing data in that format. The [2nd paragraph in its README](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser#readme) offers suggestions for other modules you can use.

Comment: Or, if the data in the `POST` request does not require `multipart`, it can be sent as [`x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type). This is the format that `bodyParser.urlencoded()` parses.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing out. My knowledge of HTTP is limited, so didn't knew about form-urlencoded. That way, my node.js can properly handle the post requests from the little angular frontend. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In general, an express app needs to specify the appropriate [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) in order for `req.body` to contain the body.

[EDITED]

1. If you required parsing of url-encoded (non-multipart) form data, as well as JSON, try adding:

   ```
   // Put this statement near the top of your module
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


   // Put these statements before you define any routes.
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   ```

   First, you'll need to add [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) to the `dependencies` property of your `package.json`, and then perform a `npm update`.
2. To handle multi-part form data, the `bodyParser.urlencoded()` body parser will not work. See the [suggested modules here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser#readme) for parsing multipart bodies.

Comment: The OP shows `body-parser` is being used. The module does not, however, support `multipart` parsing.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a reference to suggested modules for multipart form parsing. Thanks to @Jonathan for the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed, I was sending form-data, not knowing the server was able to accept url-encoded data. It works with the latter.

Comment: Will look at the pro&cons of url-encoded vs. form-data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 16):

I followed this
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_form_data.htm

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var forms = multer();

// apply them

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(forms.array()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// how to use

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('received the widget request');
});
```

Comment: when i `console.log(req.body)` i get `{}`

Answer (score 7):

To handle multipart/form-data request that support file upload, you need to use multer module. [npm link for multer middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: How to read the body from post before multer process the upload?

Comment: @CamiloOrtegón did you find the solution to your question in the comment above?

Comment: Same issue for me, need to handle the text data and the upload seperately.

Answer (score 6):

- For Json: Use `body-parser`.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

(you should Also send `Content-Type`: `application/json` in request header)

- For Normal Form, Or multipart form (form with files), Use `body-parser` + `multer`.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(multer().array())
```

(You should NOT send `Content-Type: application/json` in this case. you should send nothing, or `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` if you have files in form.

- in postman you should not send `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` manually. otherwise you'll get an error (`Boundary not found`). (it will add this automatically.).)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to put in this order:
bodyParser.json() first.

`app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: It'd be beneficial to have an explanation as to why.

Comment: Carles Alcolea, Both are middleware that will be executed in this order. I have not looked the source code, But I would bet that with urlenconded first if the body is a JSON it might send an error back instead of skip and call the next middleware. This might be what the JSON module does, it is not a JSON, skip (call next()) instead of sending an error back and call the next middleware.

Comment: I meant it as in editing your answer adding a much-needed explanation for anyone who reads it. It's much more educative and clear when we justify our answers. It also helps us make sure we are sure of our answer ;P

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not sing enctype as multipart/form-data, body parser does not support it.
use below line before you define any route.

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that in my case I was not using "name" attribute with the HTML input tags. I fixed it by changing:

**This**

```
<input id="first_name" />
```

**To**

```
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" />
```