# req.body is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, mongoose

i am trying to put array of data from inputs form at once from reactjs to nodejs mongodb API. It is working fine with Postman but when i try to send data from reactjs form it shows an error in the nodejs expressJs backend below:

`$each: [...req.body], ^ TypeError: req.body is not iterable`
And in console at browser it is showing error as for frontend :

`xhr.js:247 PUT http://url net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

reactjs frontside is :

```
const { addFluidTopatient } = useFluidContext();
const { patientId } = useParams();
// input
const [fluids, setInputs] = useState([{
  fluidname: "",
  fluidquantity: "",
  fluidtakentime: ""
}]);
const handleChange = (event, index) => {
  let {
    name,
    value
  } = event.target;
  let onChangeValue = [...fluids];
  onChangeValue[index][name] = value;
  setInputs(onChangeValue);
};
const handleInputFluidsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //  console.log(JSON.stringify(fluids))
  addFluidTopatient(JSON.stringify(fluids), patientId)
}
```

Axios Api

```
  const addFluidTopatient = async (fluids,patientId) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_FLUID_LOADING" });
    try {  
     // console.log(fluids,patientId);
      const res = await axios.put(`${API}/fluidchart/takenfluid/${patientId}`,
       {
        fluids:fluids
        }
      );
   const fluids = await res.data;
   console.log(fluids)
   dispatch({ type: "ADD_FLUID", payload:fluids});
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_FLUID_ERROR" });
    }
  };
```

below is my controller.js

```
const AddDailyFluidchart = async (req, res) => {
  // check if user is already in fluid list

  const newfluid = await patientfluidModel.findOneAndUpdate({
    patient: req.params.userId,
  }, {
    $push: {
      fluids: {
        $each: [...req.body],
      },
    },
  }, {
    new: true
  });

  res.status(200).json(newfluid);
};
```

here is mongoose schema

```
  {
    patient: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Pateint",
      required: true,
    },
    totalfluidtobetaken: {
      type: String,
    },
    fluids: [
      {
        fluidavailable: {
          type: String,
          
        },
        fluidname: {
          type: String,
     
        },
        fluidquantity: {
          type: String,
          
        },
        fluidtakentime: {
          type: String,
          
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: `req.body` is an object, it cannot be used in array with spread operator

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```js
const res = await axios.put(`${API}/fluidchart/takenfluid/${patientId}`,
   {
      fluids:fluids
   }
);
```

It looks like you have assigned your array to the key `fluids`. That means in your `$push` you need to update like so:

```js
$push: {
   fluids: {
      $each: [...req.body.fluids],
   },
},
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the  `[...req.body]` syntax you can just pass the `fluids` array directly into the `axios.put` like so:

```js
const res = await axios.put(`${API}/fluidchart/takenfluid/${patientId}`,fluids);
```

In this case `req.body` will now be an array and is now iterable.

Answer (score 0):

req.body is object. object is {}. object has key and value.
but array is [].

read below article.

[Req.body is not iterable in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166826/req-body-is-not-iterable-in-node-js)