# Body-Parser doesn't read request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, body-parser

When I send request like FormData via axios, body-parser doesn't read parameters. But when I send request like json, it reads. I use form-data because I sent imageFile so I have to use FormData.

Also I use express-validator, it always gives error because it can not read parameters. By the way, I don't try parse image with body-parser. I use multer. My problem is that body-parser can not read paramaters except image.

Html Part :

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("email", "1@gmail.com");
formData.append("name", "1");
formData.append("password", "12345678901");
let imagefile = document.querySelector('#uploadImg');
formData.append("myFile", imagefile.files[0])
let url = "http://localhost:8080/;
axios({url: url,
       data: formData,
       method: "Post",
       headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`,
        }
    }).then(x => {
      console.log(x);
    })
```

Node.js Part :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/html" }));

app.post(
  "/sa",
  [
    check("email", "Email Hatalı").isEmail(),
    check("name", "Name Hatalı").isLength({ min: 5 }),
    check("password", "Password Hatalı").isLength({ min: 10 })
  ],
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      console.log(errors.mapped());
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    res.send(200);
  }
);
```

Express-Validator Error Output :

```
{ email:
   { value: undefined,
     msg: 'Email Hatalı',
     param: 'email',
     location: 'body' },
  name:
   { value: undefined,
     msg: 'Name Hatalı',
     param: 'name',
     location: 'body' },
  password:
   { value: undefined,
     msg: 'Password Hatalı',
     param: 'password',
     location: 'body' } }
```

**I have only one problem here. Body-parser don't parse request and validation read empty parameter.**

Comment: Express.js should be used `busboy` for any file transfer. You cannot transfer files with `body-parser`. You also made Content-Type `multipart/form-data`, and `body-parser` can't parse it.

Comment: when i delete request header part and request image parameter, body-parser still can't parse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js (with express & bodyParser): unable to obtain form-data from post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347394/node-js-with-express-bodyparser-unable-to-obtain-form-data-from-post-reques)

Comment: Express.js does not support `multipart/form-data`. So you should use another endpoint for JSON data, and another endpoint for your files. But if you still want to request same endpoint, In client side, you can have a buffer property in your json data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `FormData` (mime type `multipart/form-data`) which is not supported by `body-parser`:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

The wording in the documentation may be a bit confusing because most developers do not realize that form data is transmitted as `multipart`.

You have two choices:

1. Use another module to parse form-data. I personally have used `formidable` but `body-parser` has a list of suggestions of modules that can work.
2. Send your request as URL-encoded instead of form-data:

   ```
   let urlData = "";
   urlData += "email=1@gmail.com&";
   urlData += "name=1&";
   urlData += "password=12345678901&";
   urlData += "myFile" + // well.. this is problematic
   ```

If you are going to use URL-encoded data you will need to convert the image data to a string. You can do this with base64 encoding. On the front-end you can draw the image in a `canvas` then use the canvas API to get a data url.

Then on the server you must convert the data url back into a binary buffer but this is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

To solve undefined error(from express-validator) Your require statements should be in sequence, could you please try with this sequence?

This require statement  must be after the body parser line so add this after

```
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
```

after

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/html" }));
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but still same :( it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multer before express validator

```
  var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) // or whatever you config

app.post(
    "/sa", upload(xx), [ your validations ], ( req , res ....
```

Comment: i tried witout upload image, but still doesnt work. My problem is body-parser can not pars request.

Comment: body parser doesn't support multi part form data please check [body-parser package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) , body parser docs recommend to use other lib to parse multi part bodies