# Undefined req.body Values When Sending Form Data via Ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, body-parser

I'm using Ajax to send form data to the server, but I'm encountering an issue where I'm getting undefined values when I try to access req.body.name on the server side. However, the file upload part is working correctly, and the files are being stored on the server. It's just the string data, such as 'name' and 'price,' that is not being received correctly.

Client-Side Code (JavaScript):

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const data = new FormData();

  for (let i = 0; i < selectedImages.length; i++) {
    data.append('uploadedImages', selectedImages[i]);
  }

  data.append('discription', document.getElementById("discription").value);
  data.append('pric', document.getElementById("pric").value);
  data.append('currencyButtonTxt', document.getElementById("currencyButtonTxt").value);
  console.log(data.get('pric'));

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/newitem", true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      } else:
        console.error("Error:", xhr.statusText);
      }
    };

  xhr.send(data);
});
```

Server-Side Code (Node.js with Express):

```
app.post("/newitem", function (request, response) { 
  const name = request.body.name; // Assuming the name is in the request body
  const description = request.body.discription;
  const price = request.body.pric;
  const currency = request.body.currencyButtonTxt;    
  const file = request.body.uploadedImages;

  console.log("new item page all data  name " + name + " description " + description + " price " + price + " currency " + currency + " the file " + file);

  // Additional server-side code...
});
```

Comment: Have you loaded the form-data body parser?

Comment: I have initialized body-parser      is ther a library form-data-body-parser that shall i initialize it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347394/node-js-with-express-bodyparser-unable-to-obtain-form-data-from-post-reques

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, but I appreciate your help