Trouble Accessing req.body in Middleware: Getting Empty Response
I'm encountering an issue while trying to access req.body within a middleware function in my Node.js application. Whenever I attempt to access req.body, it consistently returns empty, despite expecting data to be present in the request body. I've checked my middleware setup and made sure that body-parser middleware is correctly configured, yet the problem persists.
Could anyone shed some light on why req.body might be empty in this scenario? What are some common pitfalls or misconfigurations that could lead to this behavior?
userExists.js
I've already confirmed the following:
Middleware Order: I've ensured that the middleware responsible for parsing the request body is placed before the middleware where I'm trying to access req.body.
Parsing Configuration: body-parser is set up to handle JSON bodies using bodyParser.json(), matching the content type of my requests.
Request Content-Type: The Content-Type header of the incoming request is appropriate for the type expected by body-parser.
Body Data Integrity: I've verified that the request contains a body with data; it's not being sent empty.
Despite these checks, I'm still at a loss as to why req.body remains empty. Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
const User = require("../Model/userSchema");

const userExists = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;

  console.log(req.body);

  console.log("email:", email);
  console.log("password:", password);
  console.log("confirmPassword:", confirmPassword);

  const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (emailExist) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Email Id already exists" });
  }

  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Passwords do not match" });
  }

  next();
};

module.exports = userExists;


index.js
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const connectDB = require("./db/db");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const { storage } = require("./config/storage");
const { register } = require("./controllers/user");
const userExists = require("./middleware/userExist");

const app = express();

dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
const upload = multer({ storage });

//routes
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

//routes with files

app.post("/api/auth/register", userExists, upload.single("file"), register);

connectDB();

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Note:- I created a userExist middleware to check if a user with the same email ID already exists. If a user with a matching email is found, images will not be uploaded to the cloud. Additionally, if the user's password and confirmation password do not match, the image will also not be uploaded to the cloud.

try using
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));```


instead of 
```app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));```

I tried but thats not working

Here the issue is order of middleware execution .
app.post("/api/auth/register",upload.single("file"), userExists, register);

You need to check the order of middleware , if any middleware that rely on parsed data.

Create one testing route and check is it printing anything ?
app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body)
  });




I created a userExist middleware to check if a user with the same email ID already exists. If a user with a matching email is found, images will not be uploaded to the cloud. Additionally, if the user's password and confirmation password do not match, the image will also not be uploaded to the cloud.

Did you check on content type of body ?

As @Jack has requested, please try the test with the test route path "/test" and check req.body's accessibility.

Yes i checked and after i changes like this app.post("/api/auth/register",upload.single("file"), userExists, register); i am getting response from body but i want create a middle which going to check if user already exist if then my file will not be uploaded on cloud i created this middle ware from that purpose

Are you saying it worked with test route ? and in this ("/api/auth/register",upload.single("file"), userExists, register) also ?

Don’t forget the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

Yes it worked but i want that middleware excute before upload.single() so that when user email id already exist it stops uploading image to cloudinary.

The issue is the conflict between enctype=”multipart/form-data” and the middleware body-parser.
Please see the note documented about body-parser. “This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:” Citations : https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html . This question is already answered by the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347394/node-js-with-express-bodyparser-unable-to-obtain-form-data-from-post-reques .

....  The solution may be to do some adjustments in the application code. Option 1) First do the authentication and as the second stage ask for the file and then perform upload, track the authentication status through a hidden form field, or a cookie. Option 2) Please retain the existing process as it is, perform upload first, followed by authentication, if authentication fails, please delete the file fs.unlink.

Oh that's time it works i check if email exists if it exist it will destroy the uploaded image. But this process is little bit slower but it works

Hi, Is the issue still persisting ?

No, the issues is solved on the basis of your above suggestion.

Ok, Thank you for your confirmation. There is a better way of handling the same. Instead to delete the file, the deletion process can be aborted based on validation status. The below post of mine explains the same. Please see if it is useful to you, especially to avoid the delay you had experienced.

As we have discussed over the comments, there is a conflict between Multer and Express body-parser. While Mutler will work only with multipart/form-data, body-parser will fail in that case. Therefore any validations based on the req.body created by body-parser will be impossible.
However, Multer can do validations. It allows validations during the process of upload. As one of the options, fileFilter property in Multer can be used for custom validations too. The citations below show similar questions and answers.
The example code below shows the same under the context of your requirement.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

const upload = multer({
  dest: './uploads',
  fileFilter: async function (req, file, cb) {
    const checkUserId = async (userid) => {
      if (userid > 0 && userid < 10) {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(new Error(`${userid} is an invalid userId - valid ids [1-9]`));
      }
    };
    await checkUserId(req.body.userid);
  },
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('picture'), (req, res, next) =>
  res.send('uploaded')
);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`Error occurred : ${err}`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

Citations

Stop upload for all files when validation fails #407

How to validate multiple file uploads with multer expressjs



Hi, Please see if this post helps you.
